# iOS cordova app performance profiling

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, performance-testing, hybrid-mobile-app

We have built a hybrid app for iOS using Cordova and now we would like to do some performance profiling in the actual device (specifically around Javascript execution time, DB access times etc). Are there any tools available in iOS that can be used for performance profiling of such apps ?

Comment: did you find a toold to do profiling? webinspector has timelines which does not contain a cpu profile like chrome does

Comment: Unfortunately no !!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has some documentation on measuring the performance of Cordova apps, including on iOS. It involves using Safari on desktop to connect to the Webview on iOS, and use the JavaScript timeline profiler:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/tips-workarounds/measuring-performance?view=toolsforcordova-2017